# Map series of vectors to single vector using LSTM in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

Suppose I have a vector of features that changes over time and wanted this to map to a single vector for use as a layer in classification. How would this be implemented in Keras? Example:

```
Input:  <1.0, 2.0, 3.0>  ->  <1.1, 1.9, 3.2>  ->  ...
Output: <1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0>
```

The Keras docs say that the LSTM object takes in 3 dimensions, but I'm not sure how to express that in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LSTM takes inputs in `[batch_size, time_steps, input_dim]`. In your case you could treat each vectors as a timestep. So on input with two timesteps would be :

```
[<1.0, 2.0, 3,0>, <1.1, 1.0, 3.2>] which maps to <1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0>
```

As an example:

```
input_dim = 3
num_steps = 2

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(16, input_shape=(num_steps, input_dim)) # output 2d [batch_size, 16]
model.add(Dense(4)) # output [batch, 4]

# ... more layers
```

Dont be afraid to read the docs they are done well. https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm

Comment: I have a hard time understanding LSTM's.... What is the output shape of the LSTM layer in this example?

Comment: with `input_shape=(num_stems, input_dim)`, it's always going to expect `num_steps` timesteps, right? I understand this is needed because we "unroll" the RNN/LSTM to a fixed size for the purposes of training. But what happens after training when you want to feed in more (or fewer) time steps, but still expect the same output shape?